# So i haven't have a chance to open my android project for a couple of months and this is what happens when i run it now

Tags: android, android-studio

Android resource linking failed

> C:\Users\STUDENT_29\Desktop\ITSPROJECT\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3867:
>   error: style attribute 'attr/textColorError (aka
>   com.example.motasemx.itsproject:attr/textColorError)' not found.

error: failed linking references.

please help me i am planning to update my android app

Comment: Try to remove .idea and .gradle directory from the project level and remove the build directory from the app level and then clean and rebuild your project and also try to restart by File menu - Invalid cache and restart option

Comment: @Navin ok sir ill try to do just that thank you

Comment: @Navin it doesnt work sir im getting the same error

Comment: can you find where to use "textColor" in your app any xml file, the attr is not available but still you are using the or might be possible it used in a wrong way

Comment: @Navin yes sir i do have it i tried to edit it from <item name="textColorError">@color/bt_error_red</item> to <item name="android:textColorError">@color/bt_error_red</item> and nothings happening

Comment: Hello try to remove it please check below url   https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-android/issues/149  The use of textColorError in the style bt_add_card_activity_theme blocks users from building with SDK and support library 28

Comment: thank you so much @Navin i appreciate your help

Comment: You most welcome ardee Rebagos

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with one of your attributes. Called : *textColorError*.

> Go at values and check if that exist, if not and is wanted give a value to the **textColorError** that you have already declared there.